# How to calculate Duration?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 dateTimePickers in my winform. 1st dateTimePickers is for Start date and the other one is for End Date, now I just want to enter start date @ end date from those dateTimePickers and I get duration in my textbox automatically.

Answer (score 6):

You can calculate the duration (which is called [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .NET) by substracting two dates:

```
TimeSpan ts = dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

You can get the total amount of seconds for example like this:

```
double seconds = ts.TotalSeconds;
```

Set a textbox like this (you have to hook up any event to trigger this, like the [`ValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.valuechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the `DateTimePicker`):

```
textBox1.Text = seconds.ToString("N0");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use DateTime Subtract method whuch return a TimeSpan and then convert Result to Day or Month or year using TimeSpan class methods

good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
public partial class CalculateDuration : Form
{
    public CalculateDuration()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    //Computes the duration in days
    private void Duration()
    {

        if (this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Day > this.dateTimePicker2.Value.Day)
        {
            if (this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month == this.dateTimePicker2.Value.Month)
            {
                this.durationTextBox.Text = (-(this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Day - this.dateTimePicker2.Value.Day)).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                this.durationTextBox.Text = (this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Day - this.dateTimePicker2.Value.Day).ToString();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            this.durationTextBox.Text = (this.dateTimePicker2.Value.Day - this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Day).ToString();
        }
    }

    //This events is trigered when the value of datetimepicker is changed
    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Duration();
    }

    private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Duration();
    }
}
```